# RelativeStrengthIndex data

Tags: curated-data

I would like to extract the RSI data of a certain stock, let just say the SPX index.
How to do that? Or, alternatively, how to calculate the RSI from FinancialData?

`FinancialData["^SPX", "OHLCV", {DateList[{2016, 12}], Today}]`

Comment: Have you seen [`RelativeStrengthIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/indicator/RelativeStrengthIndex.html) and [`FinancialIndicator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialIndicator.html) ? It appears they're only for the trading charts though. You'll probably need to use `MovingMap` to compute it yourself from the prices given by `FinancialData`

Comment: indeed, I can visualize RelativeStrengthIndex in a chart. But I would like to work on the data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FinancialIndicator["RelativeStrengthIndex", n] @ data` to get a time series of  ***"the ratio of n-period exponential moving averages for gains and losses rescaled to be between 0 and 100"*** or `FinancialIndicator["RelativeStrengthIndex"]` to get the same with default `n = 14`:

```
data = FinancialData["^SPX", "OHLCV", {DateList[{2016, 12}], Today}]

rsi = FinancialIndicator["RelativeStrengthIndex"]@ data;

rsi["Path"] // Short[#, 5] &
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[rsi]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you use `FinancialIndicator["RelativeStrengthIndex"]` with the `"Close"` series as input:

```
closes = data[[All, 2, 4]];

rsib = FinancialIndicator["RelativeStrengthIndex"] @ closes;

ListLinePlot[rsib]
```

[image]

Using `n = 60`:

```
rsi60 = FinancialIndicator["RelativeStrengthIndex", 60]@ data;

DateListPlot[rsi60]
```

[image]